API LOCATIONSERVICES. API is not available on this DEVICE


I'm using UROVO DT40 SCANNER....
Just want to solved the issue on my scanner I use it at my work in Lazada as pick up courier. Once I click on arrived is shows API locationservice even when I'm connected on WiFi and the location of the apps was enabled.

Are you developing this app or just using it as an end user? If you are developing it, the question needs more details. If you are just using it, this isn't a software development question suitable for Stack Overflow. Anyway, I'd guess the app tries to use Google Location Services API that's an optional dependency and not even available for all devices as it's part of the Google Play services.
